# Upload to a FTP server using Winsock2 and C++

Tags: c++, ftp

I'm learning winsock2, and I made my own chat programs with it.
Now I just wonder if it is possible to make a program that can connect to a FTP server and upload a file.
I have found many "tutorials" on the Internet, but they all seem to use their own library, and not winsock2.

How do I connect to FTP with winsock2?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the FTP protocol. All that is different when connecting to an FTP server is that there are rules about what signals to send as theses are described by the protocol.

[For information about the signals and structure of messages](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ftp.htm)

An example of logging into an ftp server assuming that `sock` is a socket connected to the ftp port (21) of the ftp server.

```
char loginMsg[] = "USER MyName\r\nPASS MyPass\r\n";
char responce[4] = {'\0'};
send(sock, loginMsg, strlen(loginMsg), 0);
recv(sock, responce, 3, 0);
if (strcmp(responce, "230") != 0)
    // Could not log in to the ftp server
```

Comment: That is a poor way to implement it.  For starters, `USER` and `PASS` are separate commands, with their own individual responses.  You have to send the `USER` command first, read its reponse, then send the `PASS` command only if allowed.  As for reading the responses, they are much more complex then simply reading 3 characters.  They have text messages, line breaks, can be multi-line, etc.

Comment: This was not intended to be a perfect example but simply to demonstrate that there FTP being a protocol has predefined messages to send and receive.